# Tkinter (Save an entry Input)

Tags: python, tkinter

So I want to make a code that could save an entry point, well I already did it, but a problem came up
So here's my code :

```
import tkinter as tk

def players():
    global p1, p2
    p1 = plyr1.get()
    p2 = plyr2.get()

    #USERNAMES
    if (p1 != "") or (p2 != "") or (p1 != p2):
        print("Player 1 = "  + p1)
        print("Player 2 = "  + p2)

    if (p1 == "") or (p2 == ""):
        frame1.tkraise()
        messagebox.showerror("INVALID USRNAME", "PLEASE FILL THE ENTRY POINT !")

    elif p1 == p2:
        print(p1 + " (Player 1's username)"+ " and " + p2 + " (Player 2's username)"+ " ARE SAME")
        frame1.tkraise()
        messagebox.showerror("INVALID USERNAME", "PLEASE USE DIFFERENT USERNAME !")

    else :
        frame2.tkraise()

root = tk.Tk()

.
.
.

tk.Label(frame3, text = "Player 2 = ", font = _font).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
**p2_data = tk.Label(frame3, text = p2, font = _font )**
p2_data.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'E')
```

So, on that bolded line, it says p2 is not defined. Any ideas why and how to fix it?

Comment: I assume you set up the label before `players()` gets called and therefore `p2` is not yet defined. Just put `p2 = ""` somewhere above your label.

Comment: I already put p2 = "" above  players()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not returned the variable correctly. In your function you make the variables global. It is common practice to limit the use of global variables, and instead return the variables from the function to the code, i.e. `return your_variable` and to get the returned variable and store it, in the rest of the code, write `your_variable = your_function()`

Variables in the function are *local*. They need to be *returned* to the main code.

For example:

```
def your_function():
   widget_input = entry_widget.get()
   
   # returns your variable to the rest of the code
   return widget_input


# stores the output of the function in a variable
your_var = your_function()
```

Since you have two variables, you will need to return both of them and save both of them:

```
def your_function():
   input1 = widget1.get()
   input2 = widget2.get()
   
   return input1, input2


va1, var2 = your_function()
```

Comment: Well I already call the function, but I'm not showing it

Comment: Do you call the function before you use the variable `p2`?

Comment: Do you define `plyr2`? Try to print `p2` after you define it in the function and see if that returns anything.

Comment: That means you have not returned the variable correctly. In your function you make the variables global. It is common practice to limit the use of global variables, and instead return the variables from the function to the code, i.e. `return your_variable` and to get the returned variable and store it, in the rest of the code, write `your_variable = your_function()`

Comment: I don't understand can you write the example?

Comment: Wait.. it's should be doesn't matter if I don't write var = function() right?, I already tried to run it, but still, it says  p1 is undefined

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you write `var = function()`. `p1` would probably be undefined because you don't have `p1` returned to the code.

Comment: Have you saved the variables separately? I.e. `var1, var2 = function()`

Comment: Okay I already write the return function and var1, var2 = function(), so the new problem came up, it says plyr1 is not defined, ply1 is the entry btw

Comment: Okay, so how do I separate the player 1 and player 2 name?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: `tk.Label(frame3, text = "Player 2 = ", font = _font).grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = 'W')
**p2_data = tk.Label(frame3, **text = p2**, font = _font )**
p2_data.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'E')`

That one. How do I suppose to declare the player 2 name from the function?

Comment: And 1 more thing, I should write `var1, var2 = players(plyr1, plyr2)` under the entry point of plyr1 and plyr2, right? not under the function?,  because if I write it under the function, it would say plyr1 and plyr2 is not defined, **and** if I write it under the entry point, the entry point is freezing and looks like the function is executed by itself

Comment: You should write both `var1, var2 = players(plyr1, plyr2)` and in the function definition have `def players(plyr1, plyr2)` as well, so that the widgets have a reference for the function. I'm still not sure what you mean by declaring the player 2 name from the function. Try to explain what you are specifically trying to do.

Comment: So if you see from my function there's `p2 = plyr2.get()`, so from that, I want to print p2 (as player 2 name) into the Tkinter. That's exactly what I'm trying to do. Owh sorry  I didn't write p2 is player 2 name on my code, my bad

Comment: The original question is resolved. I would suggest that if you have new errors arising from your code and you cannot resolve your questions, mark the correct answer on the original question as correct and post a different question to reduce the number of comments. Also to reduce the number of comments, try to figure out the problem yourself and then if you're getting really stuck post your question on Stack Overflow.